# Angular JS: Http:get on JSON created by local API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

So I'm teaching myself Angular.js. Following a tutorial I found online, I created a RESTful API  with Laravel for storing URLS. There's basic authentication set up and currently user id 1 is signed in. I want to grab the JSON that's being returned here in the index function which is all the URLs in the database where the user_id matches the authorized user's id:

```
public function index()
{
    $urls = Url::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();

    return Response::json(array(
        'error=> false,
        'urls' => $urls->toArray()),
         200
    );
}
```

I believe JSON is being returned and when I visit my local site http://readitlater.loc/api/v1/url I get an array of objects. On my index page, I have the ng-app directive being defined as an attribute of the html element:

```
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="">
```

I have a script defining a constructor function:

```
<script>
function mainController($scope, $http) 
{
    $http.get("http://readitlater.loc/api/v1/url/")
    .success(function(response) {$scope.urls = response;});
}

</script>
```

That readitlater.loc/api/v1/url is my route to the index in my API. And when I type it in the browser I get an array of objects which I'm guessing is the JSON being created. For some reason, I can't get it to display in the browser down here:

```
<body class="container" data-ng-controller="mainController">
<ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="address in urls">
        {{ address.url }}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: pls post your http response that $scope.urls has...

Comment: I tried just {{ url }}, but that didn't give me anything either.

Comment: How do I get the http response that $scope.urls has?

Comment: console.log(response); or using developer tool from browser

Comment: Response gives me back an object containing an array. Object {error:false, urls: Array[3]}. Inside the array, there are three more objects. 0: {"description: "A Great Blog" id: 2 url: "http://fideloper.com" user_id: 1}

Comment: Be sure CORS is set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comments above, your `$scope.urls` has `urls` object and this object contains `url key`. so you would change your code as follows

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="address in urls.urls">
   {{ address.url }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first urls is a controller scope variable and second one is your response object..

Comment: Presumably because the property I'm trying to access is nested inside another object called urls

Answer (score 0):

It's often handy to validate the variables you are using contain what you think.  You can do a `console.log` or `console.dir` when you set the value, but displaying them in the HTML right where you are trying to use them can help with scope problems too.  Here I would change your code to this:

```
<pre>{{urls|json}}</pre>
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="address in urls">
    {{ address.url }}
    <br/>JSON: {{address|json}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

This should quickly show you that your `$scope.urls` object looks like this:

```
{
    error:false,
    urls: [
        { description: "A Great Blog", id: 2, url: "fideloper.com", user_id: 1 }
    ]
}
```

THAT is your `$scope.urls` object, so when you repeat over it you will get the properties of the object, 'false' and the array that I assume is what you mean by urls:

```js
// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

var ctrl = app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Jason Goemaat";
  $scope.urls =     {
        error:false,
        urls: [
            { description: "A Great Blog", id: 2, url: "fideloper.com", user_id: 1 }
        ]
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>

  <pre>{{urls|json}}</pre>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="address in urls">
      {{ address.url }}
      <br/>JSON: {{address|json}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

So if you want `$scope.urls` to be your array, you can set it directly to the urls property on your return object in the $http call:

```
$http.get("http://readitlater.loc/api/v1/url/")
.success(function(response) {$scope.urls = response.urls;});
```

Now your `ng-repeat` will be iterating over the array as I think you intend...

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

var ctrl = app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = "Jason Goemaat";
  $scope.urls = [
    { description: "A Great Blog", id: 2, url: "fideloper.com", user_id: 1 }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h1>Hello, {{name}}!</h1>

  <pre>{{urls|json}}</pre>
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="address in urls">
      {{ address.url }}
      <br/>JSON: {{address|json}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```